# Creating 3 D array for LSTM model from 2D array

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, lstm

I am working on the LSTM model to predict Price.

I have a code that can convert a single column of a data frame to lagged series which can be fed to LSTM.

The shape of the following is  - (n, timesteps, 1)

But, I want to do the same with the al columns of my data, preparing Xtrain, y_train etc.

Suppose, If I have 8 columns, it should be of shape (n, timesteps, 8)

Below is my code for single column:

```
scaled_train <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(CLOSE_HA) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(CLOSE_HA = (CLOSE_HA - scale_factors[1]) / scale_factors[2])


prediction <- 1
lag <- prediction*24


scaled_train <- as.matrix(scaled_train)
# we lag the data 24 times and arrange that into columns
x_train_data <- t(sapply(
  1:(length(scaled_train) - lag - prediction + 1),
  function(x) scaled_train[x:(x + lag - 1), 1]
))

dim(x_train_data)
# now we transform it into 3D form
x_train_arr <- array(
  data = as.numeric(unlist(x_train_data)),
  dim = c(
    nrow(x_train_data),
    lag,
    1
  )
)


y_train_data <- t(sapply(
  (1 + lag):(length(scaled_train) - prediction + 1),
  function(x) scaled_train[x:(x + prediction - 1)]
))

y_train_arr <- array(
  data = as.numeric(unlist(y_train_data)),
  dim = c(
    nrow(y_train_data),
    prediction,
    1
  )
)



x_test <- df$CLOSE_HA[(nrow(scaled_train) - prediction + 1):nrow(scaled_train)]
```